# If $C$ is a curve with endpoints $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, show that $\int_{C}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}ds\ge1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, curves

Let $I=\int_{C}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}ds$. So far, I have only managed to prove that $I\ge\sqrt{2}-{1\over2}$, the proof of which is below.

Let $c(t)$ be a unit speed parametrization of $C$ such that $c(0)=(0,1)$ and $c(L)=(1,0)$, where $L$ is the length of $c$. Let $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Notice that $f(c(t))=\|c(t)\|$ and $\|c'(t)\|=1$ since $c$ is unit speed.

Then, $I=\int_{C}fds=\int_{0}^Lf(c(t))\|c'(t)\|dt=\int_{0}^L\|c(t)\|ds$. Since $c$ is unit speed, $-1\le{d\over{dt}}\|c(t)\|dt\le1$. Also, $\|c(0)\|=\|c(L)\|=1$. So, if $L\ge2$, then $\int_{0}^{1}\|c(t)\|dt\ge{1\over2}$. Similarly, $\int_{L-1}^{L}\|c(t)\|dt\ge{1\over2}$, so $\int_{0}^{L}\|c(t)\|dt\ge{1}$, meaning we now only need consider $L<2$.

If $L<2$, then $\int_{0}^{L\over2}\|c(t)\|dt\ge{L\over{2}}(1-{L\over2})+{L^2\over8}\le\int_{L\over2}^{L}\|c(t)\|dt$, so $\int_{0}^{L}\|c(t)\|dt)\ge{L-{L^2\over4}}$.

Finally, since the distance between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is $\sqrt2$, $L\ge\sqrt2$. Since $L-{L^2\over4}$ is increasing over the interval $[\sqrt2,2]$, this implies $I\ge\sqrt2-{{\sqrt2}^2\over4}=\sqrt2-{1\over2}$.

This bound is somewhat close to $1$ at approximately $0.914...$, however I have been unable to find any way to proceed with improving upon my current inequality. How can I prove the desired result?

Comment: It's hard to know what techniques you have available. Do you know the Euler-Lagrange equations from the calculus of variations?

Comment: I do not, but if that is the best way of solving it then I would be happy to read the answer and try to understand it (this question is just asked out of interest, so if the solution is out of my reach, so be it)

Comment: I have never seen this question before, and the Euler-Lagrange equations do not look pretty. I'm guessing that the minimizing path consists in going along line segments from $(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. This does give the value of $1$.

Comment: Yes that is the path I found too. I was hoping that since the question could be asked so cleanly it could perhaps be solved by means within my reach but perhaps my hopes were too high :)

Comment: The good news is: As horrible as the Euler-Lagrange equations are for this problem, I can verify that any (piecewise-) linear path is a solution. I have no idea what other solutions they might have.

Answer (score 3):

Suitably interpreted (for example by Riemann sum) with $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,0)$, $$\int_A^B \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}\geq \int_A^B |xdx|+|ydy|$$$$\geq \frac 12+\frac 12=1,$$ where the first inequality follows from C-S, and the last minimum is achieved if both $x$ and $y$ are monotone.